# Web app on jetty stops loading when it gets to Spring Security context file

Tags: spring-security, jetty, java

Let me preface this by saying that everything I know about Spring and Jetty, I've learned in the process of trying to debug this issue: I have this one context file in a war, that is just setting up the authentication manager and the http-basic security model.  One one computer, it works fine but on another computer -- and of course the one I'm trying to deploy to -- jetty's log stops after it attempts to load that file.

The file isn't doing anything exotic, just pretty much following along every example on the net for getting a shell up and running to improve on later:

```
    <security:http>
            <security:http-basic></security:http-basic>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/dcap" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/LCL/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <security:authentication-provider>
                    <security:user-service>
           <security:user name="test" password="testpass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                    </security:user-service>
            </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Now, I've played around with this and if I comment out the first block, I get the same result, and if I comment out the second block, I get the same result.  If I comment out both blocks, however, Jetty actually starts, instead of hanging during the configuration stage, but throws an exception that it can't find springSecurityFilterChain, which of course makes sense.

So, I guess my question is, what differences could exist in a machine environment that would cause this file to fail to load on one machine while it works on another?  (The one I'm afraid it might be is that on the machine it's working on I'm using the sun jvm, while on the machine I'm on, I have to use openjdk.) And are there any additional steps I can take to debug issues like this where the start-up-log from Jetty just stops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was insufficient entropy in the RNG.  Downloaded and installed RNG tools, and plugged it into urandom, and it worked like a charm.